# The AJAX form works, but success is not met

Tags: javascript, json

The form of sending through `AJAX` works. If not in the `JSON` format, then`success` is executed. If the format `JSON` is not. I do not know what the problem is.

---

```
  $('#registration').submit(function(event) {
   var arrPhones= [],
       arrUserInfo = [arrPhones],
       arrForm = document.getElementById('registration');
      event.preventDefault();
    if(registFormValidation()) { 

      //...

      }
      var data = 'phones=' + JSON.stringify(arrUserInfo);
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  'regist.php',
        dataType: 'JSON',  
        data: data,
        error: function(error) { console.error(error); },
        success: function( response ) {
          jQuery('#update_form')[0].reset();
        } 
      });
    }
  })
```

---

```
ERROR

{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}abort: ƒ (e)always: ƒ ()complete: ƒ ()done: ƒ ()error: ƒ ()fail: ƒ ()getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()getResponseHeader: ƒ (e)overrideMimeType: ƒ (e)pipe: ƒ ()progress: ƒ ()promise: ƒ (e)readyState: 4responseText: "bool(true)↵bool(true)↵string(16) "UPDAT ---> FALSE"↵    
↵"setRequestHeader: ƒ (e,t)state: ƒ ()status: 200statusCode: ƒ (e)statusText: "OK"success: ƒ ()then: ƒ ()__proto__: Object
error @ (index):288

l @ jquery.min.js:4

fireWith @ jquery.min.js:4

k @ jquery.min.js:6

(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:6

load (async)

send @ jquery.min.js:6

ajax @ jquery.min.js:6

(anonymous) @ (index):283

dispatch @ jquery.min.js:5

y.handle @ jquery.min.js:5
```

Comment: Debug using your browser's console. Perhaps server doesn't accept json data. BTW `dataType` should be set to `json` instead of `JSON`.

Comment: try adding `error: function(error) { console.error(error); }` to you ajax, to see any error

Comment: I added code @JaromandaX

Comment: Looks like it _works_ (in that the response is `200 OK`). The response body of `bool(true)↵bool(true)↵string(16)` seems to indicate your PHP could do with some work. The fact that it's not JSON means that jQuery will trigger an error trying to parse it. Is the response meant to be JSON? If not, then you definitely don't want `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: perhaps the arguments to error are not what I expected ... try `error: function(a,b,c) { console.error(a); console.error(b);console.error(c);}` - then pick whichever one of those error logs is most useful

Comment: use `console.log(response)` in success.then see what is coming in console.

Comment: Please show browser network status please